# Regex for multiple word match seperated by spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all occurences of a word in a string having spaces at front and back.

Eg: String: " Apple Apple Apple Apple ".

Here I want the match to be " Apple " and there should be 4 matches for the above scenario.

If I just put regex as `/ Apple /`, then only 1st and 3rd are matched.

I know that we can do this with lookahead and lookbehind in regex but it is not supported in safari and IE.

Comment: Please remember that java has no relationship to javascript. The regex would be  different in java, which wouldn't help you.

Comment: the `g` modifier is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Gabriel No, this is not exactly what the OP's looking for.

Comment: Then he should post his code so we don't have to guess. And to show what he tried so far. Yeah maybe the spaces around `Apple` were not mistakes.

Comment: @Gabriel He wants to be sure that the word is surrounded by spaces. The `g` modifier doesn't ensure this.

Comment: Yes, I want spaces to be also included in the match.

Answer (score 2):

You can match  `Apple` and assert a space to the right. As you know that the space is there, you can add it in the result.

```js
const regex = / Apple(?= )/g;
const s = " Apple Apple Apple Apple ";
console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[0] + " "));
```

Or you can capture  `Apple`  in group 1, and get the group 1 value denoted by `m[1]` in the code:

```js
const regex = /(?=( Apple ))/g;
const s = " Apple Apple Apple Apple ";
console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to just match the `Apple` word, you can use `(?<= )Apple(?= )`.

If the space is not strictly necessary (e.g. you want also to catch the first word of the string, which is not preceded by a space), you must use word boundaries (i.e. `\bApple\b`).

Comment: I cannot use lookbehind as it won't work in IE and safari as far as I know.
Also, I need , . ! ? to be included. word boundary will ignore those.